# Join related Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, ssms

New to SQL

Suppose we have two tables

One has got the ID and Name column :

```
+----+-------+
| ID |  Name |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Sam   |
|  1 | Dan   |
+----+-------+
```

and the second one has also got two columns as follow :

```
+----+------------+
| ID |  Relatives |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Uncle      |
|  2 | Aunty      |
+----+------------+
```

If we do inner join we would only get the rows where the condition satisfies. But i want the output to be Like

```
+------+------------+
|  ID  |  Relatives |
+------+------------+
| 1    | Uncle      |
| NULL | Aunty      |
+------+------------+
```

once only the value in the ID column should be shown. If the occurrence is twice or thrice it should come as null.

Just tell me if it is possible or not? and How for both the cases.

Comment: Google `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: I tried but the output was'nt as i expected ... please try it .. and if done then  do share

Comment: Why is the id the same for sam and dan and what links the 2 tables?

Comment: If you tried: show what you tried, the output you got and the desired one

Comment: select * from table A as a 
full outer Join table B as b
on a.id = b.id                                                                                              
                                                                                                              
 This would give all the combinations of records . Form there to get the null for id column on every repeatition was'nt looking possible

Comment: @SandeepPandey, Try my answer. It'll helps.

Comment: For every repeatitive value in ID column null should be shown but for rest of the right hand records should be there

Comment: If we do `inner join`, we will never get rows for `Aunty`

Comment: #zarruk thats what the problem is

Comment: In result, you just need data from 2nd table or from join?

Comment: yes but group by is clubbing the two records to one

Comment: And this is what you want. isn't it?

Comment: no ... i just want the record in column should be unique whenever they are same null should come .. basically it is something like inner join without the repetitive id column records

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  T1.Id,
  T2.Relatives
FROM SecondTable T2
LEFT JOIN FirstTable T1
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.Id,
         T2.Relatives
```

This is what I get exactly:

```
CREATE TABLE #a (
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
)
CREATE TABLE #b (
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #a
  VALUES (1, 'sam')
INSERT INTO #a
  VALUES (1, 'Dan')
INSERT INTO #b
  VALUES (1, 'Uncle')
INSERT INTO #b
  VALUES (2, 'Aunty')

SELECT
  T1.Id,
  T2.name
FROM #b T2
LEFT JOIN #a T1
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.Id,
         T2.name

DROP TABLE #a
DROP TABLE #b
```

**Output:**

```
Id      name
NULL    Aunty
1       Uncle
```

Hope, this is what you ask in your question.

Comment: Not as EXpected ... just one record it is returning

Comment: No, it should return two rows, because i do left join

Comment: No but the group by is clubbing the two records to one

Comment: Create table a(id int,name varchar(10)) 
Create table b(id int,name varchar(10))

insert into a values (1,'sam') 
insert into a values (1,'Dan')                                                          
insert into b values (1,'Dan') 
insert into b values (2,'Dan')

Comment: Yess Exactly ...:)

Answer (score 2):

As your question is not clear, so assuming that you need to retrieve `id` from table `a` and `name` from table `b` and you also want to avoid duplicate rows, then an option could be to use `distinct` along with `left join`:

```
select distinct a.id, b.name
from b
left outer join a
on b.id = a.id
order by id desc
```

**Result:**

```
+------+-------+
|  id  | name  |
+------+-------+
| 1    | Uncle |
| NULL | Aunty |
+------+-------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/KHYF11016)**

Comment: What i wanted was different . U supressed the same id record using distinct. I never wanted the same